# Web Application Download File located in Share Folder

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, download

Let´s suppose we have **MyFile.zip** in a shared folder:

**\\stackoverflow\path\MyFile.zip**

What i´m trying to do is to download that file through a C# Web Forms Application.

I have tried by downloading imgs from URL and works like a charm,

then I have tried by replacing an image URL by shared folder path:

.JS

```
lsLink = '\\\\stackoverflow\\path\\MyFile.zip'
downloadFile(lsLink);

...

function downloadFile() {
    //Download file automatically 
    var loHref = document.getElementById('aDownload');
    if (loHref) {
        loHref.click();
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<a id="aDownload" href="" download>
      <p id="idP" runat="server"></p>
</a>
```

But when I set the shared path as a Link it´s getting me an error when I try to download:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file://stackoverflow/path/MyFile.zip
```

Which is the way to download shared folder files through .JS or .CS file / Web C# Application?

Comment: Setup a virtual directory on your web server that points to the file share, then use the virtual path as you would any normal link... https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/articles/309/using-iis-to-enable-https-downloads-on-a-windows-server-2012-or-2016-file-share-distribution-point

Comment: So, to solve the problem it requires IIS configuration?

Comment: I wouldn't say it _requires_ it. I think that would depend on how and who is accessing the files. If this is for an Intranet site and you are on an internal network/domain you can setup a shared folder and manage access via the share permissions, though this may mean managing permissions for your website and the folder share in two places, possibly duplicating permissions between the two. From my limited experience, the virtual directory is the better choice for security and permission management.